# Apply TRIM criteria to entire column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trim

I am trying to use the `TRIM` function in MySQL to scan an entire column and remove "(inactive)" anywhere it appears in that column. My questions are (1) is this the right application of the TRIM function and (2) how can I specify to scan an entire column and remove wherever the specified condition appears? Note that I cannot just remove all parentheses here since some teams have valid parentheses in their team name.

Sample output currently:

```
|Team|
|----|
|Research (UX) Team (inactive)|
|Engineering Team|
|Data Team (inactive)|
```

Desired Output:

```
|Team|
|----|
|Research (UX) Team |
|Engineering Team|
|Data Team|
```

I know this is not functioning SQL, but hope you can see what I'm trying to do here:

```
SELECT TRIM (' (inactive)', team) as team_cleaned
```

Comment: To remove it *anywhere* use `REPLACE()` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: SELECT  TRIM('(inactive)' FROM columnname) FROM tableanme AS Trimmed_String;   try this it wil work for column which you mention

Comment: Why a space at the end of desired value is stored in the former row and is removed in the latter one?

Comment: @UmeshSulakude Didn't know about that, thanks, though it only works if the text itself is the leading or trailing, see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/308454 anyways, learned something new today!

Comment: @JorgeCampos nice. Even i didn't know that it works only leading and trailing. I tested it only for trailing only. Thanks for screenshot :)

Comment: @UmeshSulakude, when I try this and reference the column name using "...FROM teamname" the query fails because it's looking for a table with that name. Any advice?

Comment: @AlexK. I can't seem to direct REPLACE to an entire column. It appears I'd have to do this for every string combination in that column. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `' (inactive)'` with "nothing" in every field which ends with this string.

```
update <tablename> set team = replace(team, ' (inactive)', '') where team like '% (inactive)'
```

Technically you could omit the where clause as other strings would be unaltered.